# Covering of a subset with no limit point

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a metric space and $A$ a subset of $X$ be such that $A$ has no limit point in $X$. Then there exists family $\{U_a\}_{a\in{A}}$ of pairwise disjoint open sets such that $a\in{U_a}$ for each $a\in{A}$.

My attempt:

Since $A$ is closed then for any $a\in{A}$ there exists $U_a$ open set such that intersect $A$ exactly at one $a$
Now, we will construct family of these open sets as following

$$B=\{U_a: U_a \cap A = a \}$$
I have trouble to show there are pairwise disjoint.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Since $A$ has no limit point, for each $a\in A$ there is an $r_a>0$ such that $B(a,r_a)\cap A=\{a\}$. Thus, for each $x\in A\setminus\{a\}$ we have $d(a,x)\ge r_a$, where $d$ is the metric. For each $a\in A$ let

$$U_a=B\left(a,\frac{r_a}2\right)\;;$$

clearly $U_a\cap A=\{a\}$, and you should now be able to use the triangle inequality to show that these sets are pairwise disjoint.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: @Gob: Yes, I wrote my answer for the edited version.

Comment: Of course, you are right thank you

Comment: Is it important that we have a metric? Does the result hold for a **general topological space**? (Of course, for nice spaces which are metrizable, the above proof works.)

Comment: @MohithRaju: It does not hold in general. Spaces in which it does hold are said to be [*collectionwise Hausdorff*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collectionwise_Hausdorff_space). Dan Ma’s Topology Blog has a (rather complicated) [example](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/collectionwise-hausdorff/), due to R.H. Bing, of a space with many nice properties that is not collectionwise Hausdorff.